# Shared data between two comboboxes

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to share data between two(or maybe more) comboboxes, but I want to choose elements independently. For example, if I choose Object1 in first comboBox, my second ComboBox also chooses Object1, because they have same model(DefaultComboBoxModel and this model also manages chosen objects). But I don't want this behavior. I want to choose objects in my comboBoxes independently. When I choose object in first comboBox my second comboBox shouldn't change.

At this moment I'am thinking about supermodel for two models. Supermodel will send events to submodels and they will update comboboxes data, but not the state. But I think this is not the best way.

Are there more intresting and simple aproaches?

Here is the short code to understand what I mean:

```
package hello;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
public class Comboboxes extends JFrame
{
private JPanel contentPane;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Comboboxes frame = new Comboboxes();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Comboboxes()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JComboBox one = new JComboBox();
    one.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 26);
    contentPane.add(one);

    JComboBox two = new JComboBox();
    two.setBounds(10, 52, 414, 26);
    contentPane.add(two);

    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    model.addElement("Item 1");
    model.addElement("Item 2");
    model.addElement("Item 3");

    one.setModel(model);
    two.setModel(model);
}
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply create two different instances of the same ComboBoxModel-->same values+different selection?

Comment: I can, but data may change and I will have to change two instances.

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/positioning of components, that's the task of a suitable LayoutManager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a decorator for your `ComboBoxModel`. The decorator should manage the `selectedItem` property, while everything else is managed by the delegate.

You would then have 1 original model, and place different decorators on the comboboxes:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel original = ...;

DecoratedModel firstModel = new DecoratedModel( original );
JComboBox firstCombo = new JComboBox( firstModel );

DecoratedModel secondModel = new DecoratedModel( original );
JComboBox secondCombo = new JComboBox( secondModel );
```

Changes to the data can then be performed on the `original` model, which will adjust the data in all comboboxes simultaneously

Note: make sure listeners attached to the decorator receive events with the decorated model as source, and not with the delegate model. This is a common mistake when writing a decorator

**Edit**

An alternative is to have a base data structure which is not a `ComboBoxModel` and create an implementation of `ComboBoxModel` which uses that data structure. You can then create different combobox model instances which all share the same data structure.

Comment: +1 for decorating - though it took me a moment to understand what you mean with _caveat_ (might be a language problem, I would call it proper implementation of a decorating model :-)

Comment: @kleopatra that is indeed a better name. But I have seen enough decorator implementations which violate this. Therefore that I explicitly mentioned it. I adjusted it to a note

Comment: It seems like a good approach, but I don't realy now if I can implement this. But I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: @Moses I have added an implementation of this in that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16894040/928711)